# When does an integral not exist?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, stochastic-processes, expected-value

In my stochastic course, we have the following definition of the expected value in relation to the density of a function:

$$\text{ Let X be a random variable with the density of} \ f_x. \text{Then, the expected value is defined as:} \ \mathbb{E}[X]:=\int_{-\infty}^\infty tf_x(t), \text{given that the integral exists.}$$

My question is: How do I know if the integral exists or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know the same way you know if any integral exists, by considering what you are actually integrating in any particular case.

For example, consider the density
$$
f_x(t)=\begin{cases} 0 & t<1, \\
                  \dfrac{1}{t^2} & t\geq 1.
\end{cases}
$$